# Excel nested IF formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I want to set a formula that incorporates my school's attendance policy:

- 3 tardies = 1 unexcused absence
- 6 tardies = 2 unexcused absences
- and so on

The cell must reference not only the cell with the Tardy count, but also the attendance worksheet in the same workbook, and must add the two values.  For example, if the attendance page shows 1 unexcused absence and the tardy count shows 7 tardies, the formula needs to return 3.

This is what I've got:

```
 =SUM(Attendance!O9+(IF(J4>=3,1,IF(J4>=6,2,IF(J4>=9,3,IF(J4>=12,4,))))))
```

It works for 4 tardies and 1 unexcused absence, but continues to return 2 for 7 tardies and 1 unexcused absence.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much easier than using If/Then:

`=Attendance!O9+(Int(J4/3))`

The `Int` function returns the floor integer of the calculation, J4/3.  So, if J4 = 7, the result is 2. If J4=9, the result is 3, etc.

Comment: +1 Yup, and even takes care of things like 12, 15 and so on without requiring more nested `if`s :)

Answer (score 2):

Your if statements are backwards you should check for bigger numbers first in this case otherwise the first if is always true. so 7 is falling true on >= 3 therefore you get 1 + 1 = 2

EDIT - a better way to do it would be to take your J4 divide it by 3 and return the value without the remainder

```
QUOTIENT(J4, 3)
```

Comment: +1, for good explanation of why OP's formula was failling. Also, for showing another more reliable way to do this, instead of If/Then logic.

Comment: I never knew about the quotient function before.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The if part of your formula should be as follows

```
IF(J4<3,0,(IF(J4<6,1,(IF(J4<9,2,IF(J4<12,3,4))))))
```

Bear in mind that this formulae limits you to a maximum of 4 unexcused absences for tardies.

A better solution would be to use the QUOTIENT formula

```
= Attendance!O9 + QUOTIENT(J4,3)
```